# One-word descriptor

Tags: word-usage, pejorative-language

I know there is a word which is used in this context:  to describe someone who is puffed up, cocky, superior, and overly  macho.  Think of George Bush on board the aircraft carrier, exclaiming that the USA had got the job done when in fact it hadn't.

Comment: In the interest of accuracy, it should be pointed out that Bush 43 didn't actually *say* "Mission accomplished". Rather, a *banner* displaying those words was visible above him when he claimed that the US and its allies had prevailed in Iraq. Though the banner was actually produced by the White House, the question of who decided to erect the banner, and whether its message actually related to the President or to the crew of the ship, remains (ostensibly) controversial; see the relevant page on [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mission_Accomplished_speech).

Comment: Pompous seems to fit the bill.

Comment: You could say that he had *chutzpah*, though I'm not sure that quite captures the macho connotation you want.

Answer (score 2):

Probably a  [blow-hard](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/blow-hard): (from TFD)

> - a boastful and talkative person.
> - arrogant or boastful in speech or manner.

Answer (score 0):

*Arrogant*, *pompous*, *pretentious*, *over-confident* or *overly-confident* seem to fit the bill. *Full of themselves* is also valid in the context.